# Best search engine to use in a ebay-like system (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, search-engine, lucene.net

I´m developing a ebay-like system in .NET/C# ...
Is Lucene a good option to a system like that? Or maybe a simpler solution ?
The performance is the most important thing to that...

EDIT
I´ll use a Full-Text Sql Search (Is it the best option?)

Any ideas, suggestions?

Paul

Comment: A little more info might be helpful.  Are you trying to do full-text SQL queries, or are you querying files on the file system or are you querying some other kind of data source?

Comment: I´ll use a Full-Text Sql Search...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely go for [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) as you mention yourself. My experience is, that Lucene.Net has excellent performance, compared to proprietary search servers that I have had experience with.

Alternatively you can run the Java version [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) on you server and query it.

Answer (score 1):

It you're just searching on SQL data, I would just use a full-text SQL query.  Lucene, Google search and Microsoft indexing service are great options for searching on files, should you need to go that route.

Comment: In a Ebay-like app, what do you think is the best save itens/search approach?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a thing about Lucene but how about custom [Google search](http://www.google.com/cse/)?